# Acesso a diretivas de um componente

Tags: angular

Como posso ter acesso as diretivas que estão sendo aplicadas ao meu componente?

Tenho meu componente `ButtonSidenavComponent`:

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'button-sidenav',
  templateUrl: './button-sidenav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./button-sidenav.component.css', '../../../app.component.css']
})
export class ButtonSidenavComponent implements OnInit {
  
  @Input() page: String = '';
  @Input() icon: String = '';
  actualRoute: any
  element: ElementRef

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, element: ElementRef) {
    this.actualRoute = this.route.snapshot.routeConfig?.path
    this.element = element
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activateButton(this.element)
  }

  activateButton(el: ElementRef): void{
    console.log(el)
  }

}
```

Onde o template está como:

```
<button class="custom-width h-14 flex justify-start items-center pl-7 mb-1 rounded-lg">
    <span class="material-icons text-primary-light mr-4">{{icon}}</span>
    <p class="font-subtitle text-primary-light text-sm">{{page}}</p>
</button>
```

E ele está sendo inicializado como:

```
<button-sidenav [page]="'Home'" [icon]="'home'" active></button-sidenav>
```

A dúvida é, como posso ter o controle das diretivas que estão sendo aplicadas ao meu `ButtonSidenavComponent`, como adicionar ou remover diretivas do componente segundo condições aplicadas?